# Can a class inherit only declartion of members, without definition?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to simulate partial class in c++. However, there's problem when I simply use inheritance.

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QLabel *interLabel;
    QLabel *resultLabel;
    bool calculated;
    bool specialStart;
    const QMap<QString, void(MainWindow::*)()> Operators;

    // Group 1
    void setResult(const QString &str);
    void appendResult(const QString &str);
    void prependResult(const QString &str);
    void chopResult(const int &num);
    void removeResult(const int &num);
    void removeResult(const int &pos, const int &num);
    QString getResult(const bool &chopDot = true);
    void setInter(const QString &str);
    void appendInter(const QString &str, const bool &autoSpace = true);
    void prependInter(const QString &str, const bool &autoSpace = true);
    void chopInter(const int &num);
    void removeInter(const int &num);
    void removeInter(const int &pos, const int &num);
    QString chopInterOp(const int &num);
    QString removeInterOp(const int &num);
    QString getInter() const;
    QString lastOp() const;
    bool isBracketUnclosed() const;
    bool endsWithBracket() const;
    void closeAllBracket();
    bool isLastOpArithmetic() const;
    void replaceLastOp(const QString &str);

    // Group 2
    void addNumber(const QString &str);
    void calculate();
    void calculate(const QString &op);
    void arithmetic(const QString &op);
    void unarySpecial(const QString &format);
    void binarySpecial(const QString &format);
    void plus();
    void minus();
    void multiply();
    void divide();
    void equal();
    void erase();
    void dot();
    void negate();
    void ce();
    void c();
    void percent();
    void sqrt();
    void sqr();
    void inv();
    void root();
    void pow();
    void sin();
    void cos();
    void tan();
    void asin();
    void acos();
    void atan();
    void log();
    void mod();
    void fac();
    void sinh();
    void cosh();
    void tanh();
public slots:
    void buttonPushed();

};
```

This is my class definition (Quite long!)
I want to seperate declarations of member functions as two function groups, which would be setResult() ~ replaceLastOp() and addNumber() ~ tanh()

It would be nice if I simply make class Mainwindow inherit two classes (then those two classes would have to be declared and defined.)
However, it is not possible because group 2 functions use functions in group 1, and group 1 functions use member variables including interLabel, resultLabel, etc...

This is an example of a function in group 1

```
QString MainWindow::getResult(const bool &chopDot){
    QString &&result = this->resultLabel->text();
    if(chopDot){
        if(result.back() == '.'){
            this->setResult(result.chopped(1));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is an example of a function in group 2

```
void MainWindow::addNumber(const QString &str){
    if(this->calculated){
        if(!this->getInter().isEmpty() && !this->isLastOpArithmetic())
            this->setInter(this->chopInterOp(1));
        this->setResult(str);
        this->calculated = false;
    }
    else{
        if(this->getResult(false) == "0"){
            if(str == "0")
                return;
            else{
                this->setResult(str);
            }
        }
        else{
            if(this->specialStart){
                this->setResult(str);
                this->specialStart = false;
            }
            else
                this->appendResult(str);
        }
    }
}
```

So if I use inhertiance to solve this problem, I have to write it like below

```
class Group1 : public MainWindow{...};
class Group2 : public Group1{...};
```

And it looks very strange. (It seems parent and child relationship is reversed)
So, I want to simulate partial class without inheritance, or with declartion-only inheritance (if possible) so that **I don't have to declare functions again in MainWindow class.**

Comment: If your class definition gets too long, that is typically a sign that your class is responsible for doing too many things. Rather than trying to hack up a way to simulate partial classes in C++, have you considered that maybe the things you call "Group 1" and "Group 2" should be separate classes?

Comment: @Michael Kenzel I have to pass "this" as a function parameter to seperate two groups because they are interconnected. Is it OK? (Is it readable?)